# NetBeans - Packing jars in ear and include them in manifests in web and ejb modules

Tags: netbeans, jar, classpath, manifest, ear

I want to create Enterprise Application in NetBeans. This application depends on a lot additional .jars files, which will be common for WAR and EJB modules.

In particular I need to build EAR with structure:

```
myEAR.ear 
|-myWebModule.war 
| |-META-INF 
| | |-MANIFEST.MF 
| |-somefile 
| |-somefile 
| |-... 
|-myEJBModule.ejb 
| |-META-INF 
| | |-MANIFEST.MF 
| |-somefile 
| |-somefile 
| |-... 
|-additionalJar1.jar 
|-additionalJar2.jar 
|-additionalJar3.jar 
|-...
```

Some of this 'additionalJars' have to be included in Class-Path in MANIFEST.MF inside Web module, 
and some of this 'additionalJars' have to be included in Class-Path in MANIFEST.MF inside EJB module.

How to create such project in NetBeans?